# Keep email with registrar but host website elsewhere

Tags: web-hosting, dns, email, mx

I am currently building a website for a client who purchased their own domain and email on Godaddy. They have been using the email for a considerable amount of time now and only recently decided to get a website which is where I come in. There is a godaddy mobile app which is what the client uses to check their email on mobile devices and if on a desktop / laptop they just log into godaddy so they dont use any other email clients than that.

I re-directed the DNS (prior to realising that the client had email through godaddy) to my hosting provider and that all worked fine except it broke the email. Godaddy provides MX records and also CNAME but the CNAME just gives details for pop, imap and SMTP. Arent these A records?

If my client is only using Godaddy and no external clients then will I get away with just supplying the correct MX records to my hosting provider and give godaddy the new ns records?

Just to clarify. I need to host the website with a separate host but keep the email functionality on godaddy...is this possible?

Comment: Interesting question. As far as I believe we have to use hosting email feature...

Comment: This topic may be of some use: http://forums.hostgator.com/keeping-email-godaddy-after-nameserver-change-t205184.html?s=ec06a272e445898021c50053bee48f3c&amp;

Comment: Yes, you can keep your email with GoDaddy, but have a web hosting account elsewhere. Assuming that you're referring to GoDaddy's Workspace email service, you'll just need to point the MX records back to them. This explains where to find these: [Using Our Email with Domains Hosted Elsewhere](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2570/using-our-email-with-domains-hosted-elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks guys this is very helpful stuff! Everywhere I am reading that the MX records take 24 -48 hours to propagate? Is this like a maximum and its normally just an hour or 2 or should I actually expect such a long down time?

Comment: No problem. Since the DNS for the domain is also through GoDaddy, the MX records should be updated pretty quickly with them, and most major email providers (e.g., Gmail) should pick up on that within a few hours. I'd give it up to a day for the rest, so don't launch any email campaigns till then ;-)

Comment: Also, If I choose to go the A record option (as suggested in the hostgator forum) Godaddy asks for a host when adding the A record. Is the host mydomain.com or the actual host domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to keep the email with your server as it is now, log into the go daddy email accounts using something like outlook (you can do this by using the IP address of the godaddy email servers rather than the old godaddy pop/imap servers)

Setup the new email accounts using IMAP copy all the old emails to the new email accounts, and re-setup you clients email accounts using email clients and IMAP, so it syncs emails over their multiple devices.

Or if its mission critical to keep email with Godaddy its possible to do so by setting the MX records on your domain control panel to point back to Godaddys email servers.  This is all dependant on if your control panel is easy to use or not;)

Here are Godaddys MX records....

https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/How-can-I-point-my-e-mail-towards-GoDaddy#mx-records

Comment: Thanks for this...he wanted to keep using the Godaddy client(?) so ii ended up just changing the mx records and that worked out fine.

Comment: Awesome, glad its all sorted:)